# How to do dosbox autoexecutable like dosemu on Opensuse

Tags: opensuse, emulation

I was trying to migrate an DOS aplication on a dos emulator, I was pretty sure that dosemu was the answer ... but a couple of errors ocurred on the program. So I tryied dosbox.

The thing is, under putty a windows user will autenticate to the OpenSUSE server an then the program will autoexecute.

I was able to do that on dosemu but **how do I do that on dosbox?**

To do that on dosemu, I edited the `.profile` and added this:

```
stty cols 80 rows 25
dosemu
exit
```

then on the `.dosemu/drive_c/`, I edited the `autoexec.bat`

```
lredir f: software_folder
unix -s DOSEMU_VERSION
echo "Welcome to dosemu %DOSEMU_VERSION%!"
unix -e
f:
software_name
exitemu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way to change or add to the autoexec, is in the `.dosbox/dosbox-X.XX.conf`.
At the end of the file is the section ...

```
 [autoexec]
```

Place your commands after that decleration, they will execute when `dosbox` starts.

If you need to create something like a "shortcut", which is not specific to your users's `dosbox` config. You can specify commands with `-c COMMAND`.  You need one for each command, but multiple can be used.   You can also create a custom .conf file and specify that with `-conf CONF_FILE`

Specifically for the example you posted, your `[autoexec]` would look like this.

```
[autoexec]
@ECHO OFF
CLS
MOUNT F SOFTWARE_FOLDER
F:
SOFTWARE_NAME
EXIT
```

Also it's worth mentioning, I belive `dosbox` lacks an internal `MODE.COM`.  If you want to use `MODE.COM` anyway, you must load `MODE.COM` from a copied FreeDOS binary.  It might be easier to just use an alternate program, which doesn't require being loaded first.

In general, I also like both `dosbox` and `dosemu`.  I use `dosbox` for anything that is graphical, as It seems to have hassle free video support.  I use `dosemu`, when things must be run without `X`, or when they must have direct access to hardware.

Comment: thanks @TechZilla, but what I did is adding this: `dosbox "folder_of_the_softwre/the_software.exe"` on the `.profile`. then When I use putty and log in the soft executes... =D

Comment: If you already found an answer you should either accept mine :P... Or submit your own, and accept yourself.  You won't get points for a self accept, but it won't bring down your accept rating.  A bad accept rating turns off many users from submitting an answer.

Comment: However, You do get points for accepting a non-self answer.  Its always best to close out questions when possible.